# Program loops without running complete code

Tags: java, exception

I am writing an exception class for a project, and have become stumped with a problem.  The class asks for a file name with bank accounts in it, reads the file, and checks if they meet certain criteria.  If they do not meet one of these criteria, an error of type BankAccountException is thrown, which is a custom error class that simply `extends` the `Exception` class and is renamed.  The problem I am coming across is that once I enter the name of the file, the program immediately asks for the name of another file. I have been sitting on this for a while and cannot figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

```
   import java.util.*;


 import java.io.*;

   public class BankAccountProcessor{


  public static void main(String[] args){
     boolean runProgram = true;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String filename;

     while (runProgram = true){
        try{
           System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you want to parse.");
           filename = input.next();
           File file = new File(filename);
           Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
           while (inputFile.hasNext()){
              String accountLine = inputFile.nextLine();
                    if (BankAccountProcessor.isValid(accountLine) == true){
                        System.out.println("Line " + accountLine + " has been processed.");
                    }
                    runProgram = false;
           }
        }
           catch(FileNotFoundException e){
              System.out.println("That file does not exist");
           }
           catch(BankAccountException e){

           }
     }
  }

  private static boolean isValid(String accountLine) throws BankAccountException{
     StringTokenizer stringToken = new StringTokenizer(accountLine, ";");
     String tokenOne = stringToken.nextToken();
     String tokenTwo = stringToken.nextToken();
     if (stringToken.countTokens() != 2){
        throw new BankAccountException("Invalid Bank Account Info");
     }
     else if (tokenOne.length() != 10){
        throw new BankAccountException("Invalid Bank Account Info: Account Number is not 10 digits.");
     }
     else if (tokenTwo.length() < 3){
        throw new BankAccountException("Invalid Bank Account Info: Name must be more than 3 letters.");
     }
     else if (BankAccountProcessor.hasLetter(tokenOne) == true){
        throw new BankAccountException("Invalid Bank Account Info: Account Number must be all digits.");
     }
     else if (BankAccountProcessor.hasDigit(tokenTwo) == true){
        throw new BankAccountException("Invalid Bank Account Info: Account Name cannot have digits.");
     }
     return true;
  }

  private static boolean hasDigit(String str){
     for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if (Character.isDigit(c)){
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }

  private static boolean hasLetter(String str){
     for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }


 }
```

Comment: Just commenting on the coding style: The closing `}` for the try block is not indented correctly and you should at least print something if you catch an exception such as the `BankAccountException`.

Comment: My apologies, I am still in the process of writing it.

Comment: From the context of you exception strings, I am guessing that your `hasDigit()` and `hasLetter()` methods do not behave as you are expecting them to.

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning `true` to your `runProgram` variable in each loop with the `=` operator.  The result is `true` so your while loop will loop forever.  Use the `==` operator to compare:

```
while (runProgram == true)
```

or to put it more simply,

```
while (runProgram)
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the looping error, but now it is acting like there is nothing in the text file.  I realize that is not part of this question, but if you see that error, I'd appreciate help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (and I am guessing), I'd say that the file you are passing in lacks any tokens so `while (inputFile.hasNext())` returns false and it asks you for your next file.

Comment: The file I am passing in has the correct format for the tokens, so I don't think that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in some debug `System.out.println()` statements to see how far you are getting in your code. That will help you narrow down where the problem lies.